# What is the best caching engine for large datasets that do not fit in memory?

Tags: nosql, redis, membase

I would like to serve a huge numbers of keys (100 000 000+) but only a few (50 000) can fit in memory (the one that are the most asked). Does anyone have any experience with redis, membase or other? Does anyone have benchmarks of disk serving keys?

Thanks

Comment: Only 50000 keys can fit in your memory? Also, redis does not work from disk, it only saves to disk (As backup). Redis can run from Virtual Memory, but not disk.

Comment: Virtual memory is disk, and Redis VM is not the same thing as system VM.

Answer (score 0):

Salvatore Sanfilippo's response :

> This is a use case for VM, but not
>   when the difference between in-ram 
>   and not-in-ram is so big.
>
> Btw in Redis unstable the VM is
>   replaced by a new idea called 
>   "**diskstore**" that address your use
>   case, but unfortunately it is not 
>   production ready at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

If quite a lot of keys are going to be in disk and if the storage engines does not provide efficient indexing mechanism then performance will be hit severly. I don't think redis b-trees are ready yet. You can check Tokio Cabinet. It seems to provide key-value storage + btrees.

http://www.igvita.com/2009/02/13/tokyo-cabinet-beyond-key-value-store/
http://colinhowe.wordpress.com/2009/04/27/redis-vs-mysql/